# LARAVEL 5.5 Foreign key constraint is incorrectly formed'

Tags: mysql, laravel, laravel-5, foreign-keys, laravel-migrations

I am encountering "errno: 150 'Foreign key constraint is incorrectly formed'" when migrating.

I have a table that needs 3 foreign keys:

> ```
>   Schema::create('ads', function (Blueprint $table) {
>         $table->increments('id');
>         $table->string('prodname');
>         $table->string('mfrname');
>         $table->decimal('priceam');
>         $table->string('imagenametxt',500);
>         $table->string('specstxt',500);
>         $table->string('otherinfotxt',500);
>         $table->decimal('avalableqty');
>         $table->binary('validyn');
>         $table->binary('checkyn');
>         $table->binary('updatedyn');
>         $table->integer('selleridno')->unsigned();
>         $table->integer('catidno')->unsigned();
>         $table->integer('subcatidno')->unsigned();
>         $table->timestamps();
>
>     });
>
>     Schema::table('ads', function(Blueprint $table){
>         $table->foreign('selleridno')->references('id')->on('users');
>         $table->foreign('catidno')->references('id')->on('categories');
>         $table->foreign('subcatidno')->references('id')-> 
>          on('subcategories');
>     });
> ```

Users, Categories and Subcategories table are created before this table. selleridno and catidno was successfully created but in creating foreign key for subcatidno I am encountering the error. any suggestions/opinions? thank you in advance.

My Database is MySql.

Just in case you need the SubCategories table here it is:

```
Schema::create('sub_categories', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->string('subcategorycd');
            $table->string('subcategorytxt');
            $table->integer('categoryidno')->unsigned();
            $table->timestamps();

            $table->foreign('categoryidno')->references('id')->on('categories');
        });
```

Comment: I think you have problem with order of execution of the migration. Since parent table should be created first than the table in which parent id is used as foreign key.

Comment: @SagarGautam i already arranged it sir since i also encountered that kind of issue first before this. but as stated above the parent table was created first before the table that has foreign key. Thank you sir.

Comment: @punky is your table name sub_categories or subcategories please check

Comment: @saurabhkamble oh my God, I am so stupid not noticing that. Thank you sir.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This foreign key is on a table called `subcategories`:

```
$table->foreign('subcatidno')->references('id')->on('subcategories');
```

But your table is actually called `sub_categories`:

```
Schema::create('sub_categories', function (Blueprint $table) {
```

Answer (score 0):

When you get subcategory you don't need to get category as well because you get category in subcategory migrate.

And also try to get them as `user_id` and `subcategory_id` instead of `selleridno` and `subcatindo`.

See if it works.

**PS:** your subcategory creat method has issue separate foregin key just like you did for ads.

```
Schema::table('subcategory', function(Blueprint $table){ 

    $table->foreign('category')->references('id')-> on('categories'); 
});
```